# Query to check if there is a cycle in a graph with edges visited only once

Tags: gremlin, graphic, tinkerpop

How to write an query runs on my graph, that outputs 'false' if there is NO path traversing through each edge only once and return to the starting point.

Comment: This boils down to looping over all vertexes and returning true if the total number of both().count() % 2 == 0 is 0 or 2. I'm still noodling the traversal to express that.

Comment: Ye. The traversal is the trickiest part. Still trying to get it.

Answer (score 6):

I was using the following [sample graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg#/media/File:Koenigsberg_Bridges_Variations_Graph8.png):

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV().property(id, 'blue').as('b').
  addV().property(id, 'orange').as('o').
  addV().property(id, 'red').as('r').
  addV().property(id, 'white').as('w').
  addE('bridge').from('w').to('b').
  addE('bridge').from('w').to('o').
  addE('bridge').from('w').to('r').
  addE('bridge').from('w').to('r').
  addE('bridge').from('o').to('b').
  addE('bridge').from('o').to('b').
  addE('bridge').from('o').to('r').
  addE('bridge').from('o').to('r').iterate()
```

The following query returns the first possible path:

```
gremlin> g.V().sideEffect(outE("bridge").aggregate("bridges")).barrier().
......1>   repeat(bothE().or(__.not(select('e')),
......2>                     __.not(filter(__.as('x').select(all, 'e').unfold().where(eq('x'))))).as('e').otherV()).
......3>     until(select(all, 'e').count(local).as("c").select("bridges").count(local).where(eq("c"))).limit(1).
......4>   path().by(id).by(constant(" -> ")).map {String.join("", it.get().objects())}
==>orange -> blue -> white -> orange -> red -> white -> red -> orange -> blue
```

If all you need is a boolean value, then just append `.hasNext()`:

```
g.V().sideEffect(outE("bridge").aggregate("bridges")).barrier().
  repeat(bothE().or(__.not(select('e')),
                    __.not(filter(__.as('x').select(all, 'e').unfold().where(eq('x'))))).as('e').otherV()).
    until(select(all, 'e').count(local).as("c").select("bridges").count(local).where(eq("c"))).hasNext()
```