# How to avoid duplicate edges in the path in Tinkerpop 3?

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

In Tinkerpop3, we have SimplePath to prevent a traverser repeating the vertices. But what if I want it to traverse each edge only once?

For example,[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUDWZ.png).
In this graph, I want to get all the possible path if I start from V1 and traverse each edge no more than once per path and then return to V1 at last. One possible path is V1->E2->V2->E1->V1->E5->V4->E7->V3->E3->V1.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to traverse an edge only once globally or once per path? Even better: provide a small sample graph and an expected result.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz It's once per path. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this graph and just recently answered a similar question here: [Query to check if there is a cycle in a graph with edges visited only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672466/how-to-write-an-eulerian-circuit-detection-query-using-gremlin/40695998#40695998)
This should answer your question too.