# Efficient gremlin query to find a cycle in a graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, gremlin, directed-graph, tinkerpop, cycle-detection

I have a big TinkerGraph (~80.000 vertices, ~160.000 edges) and I need to detect if there is a cycle in it using the [Apache TinkerPop/Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/) query language. If any, I would like to obtain the vertices of one of the cycles.

Is there a way to write a `O(|V| + |E|)` gremlin query to find a cyclic path in a graph?

I tried using the queries from [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/recipes/#cycle-detection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40695998/2491528), but they are too slow and they time out. I suspect that they are not `O(|V| + |E|)`, but I am still learning TinkerPop and I can not evaluate the memory/time complexity of the TinkerGraph implementation.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672466/query-to-check-if-there-is-a-cycle-in-a-graph-with-edges-visited-only-once) is a similar question. Maybe that can inspire a solution specific to your problem?

Comment: I am working on it, thanks. That answer uses several gremlin features that are new to me (e.g. `select(all, ...)`)

Comment: That particular answer is also described in more detail [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#cycle-detection)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was looking at the old version `3.2.1`